# C# List loop within a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I'm working on a class project and here is what I have so far. I know the code returns true when it finds a match but I want it to keep looping until no more instances are found.

I've looked at numerous sites on `for/while` loops but I can't seem to get the syntax correct and/or it doesn't work when applying the logic.

```
public bool Remove(T toRemove)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (items[i].Equals(toRemove))
        {
            int removeIndex = i;
            for (int j = removeIndex; j < count - 1; j++)
            {
                items[j] = items[j + 1];
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use a boolean variable and set it to true if an item is found, and continue your loop until you go through all elements, then return the boolean value.

Comment: That's awesome, didn't think of that.  That did it, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the result in a variable and return it after the loop is complete:

```
public bool Remove(T toRemove)
{
    bool result = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (items[i].Equals(toRemove))
        {
            int removeIndex = i;
            for (int j = removeIndex; j < count - 1; j++)
            {
                items[j] = items[j + 1];
            }
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `bool` instead of `boolean`.

Comment: @TânNguyễn true 'dat. Momentary lapse of concentration, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to complete the loop, do not return. Instead hold the result on a var you should return at the end:

```
    public bool Remove(T toRemove)
    {
        bool result = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].Equals(toRemove))
            {
                int removeIndex = i;
                for (int j = removeIndex; j < count - 1; j++)
                {
                    items[j] = items[j + 1];
                }
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Use a boolean variable and set it to true if an item is found, 
//and continue your loop until you go through all elements, then return the boolean value.  

public bool Remove(T toRemove)
{
        bool match= false; //boolean to track if any match is found
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].Equals(toRemove))
            {
                int removeIndex = i;
                for (int j = removeIndex; j < count - 1; j++)
                {
                    items[j] = items[j + 1];
                }
                match= true;
            }
        }

        return match;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is declare a bool called "result" and instantiate it to false.  In the loop where you are returning true, set "result" to true.  At the end, where you are returning false, return "result"